# Filter list by date and search through list

Tags: vuejs2

I need to figure out how to order by date ascending and how I can add search to my list.

Here is example structure: https://jsfiddle.net/franso/jr7dsef3/

```
<div id="app">
 <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search">
 <select v-model="title">
   <option value="Show all">Show all</option>
   <option value="Title 1">Title 1</option>
   <option value="Title 2">title 2</option>
 </select>
 <select v-model="name">
   <option value="Show all">Show all</option>
   <option value="Name 1">Name 1</option>
   <option value="Name 2">Name 2</option>
 </select>
 <div class="list" v-for="post in filteredAndOrdered">
  <div class="list__wrapper">
   <div class="list__item">{{ post.title }}</div>
   <div class="list__item">{{ post.name }}</div>
   <div class="list__item">{{ post.FinalApplicationDate }}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the [mcve] guidance? Someone might be far more willing to take a stab at an answer if you presented your results and you picked either making the sort the problem to solve here or adding search. If you just need sort - remove all mention of search and focus on the mcve guidelines

Comment: Thank you @Ram i got the array sort() working.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @bmike

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.sort() for sorting date and use @change function on input tag for using search

[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)